# Is a string repeated in the given grouping in a given time window

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-28","2020-08-15","2020-01-01","2020-05-01","2020-03-01")), string = c('a','b','b','a','a','a','a','b'))
```

I need to determine, whether a value of the string is repeated again in future observations for the same ID, but only if the date is more than 90 days from now and at the same time less than a year from now. It also needs to be used inside of a dplyr pipe.

The result should look like this:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

I have tried ave(), but couldn't make the double conditional grouping work. Also if I understand it correctly, ave is calculated from the first observation to the last, so not sure how to make it work from the end.

Alternatively, I found the runner package that could be useful for this.

Comment: I don't understand how you get first value as `TRUE` and 5th value as `FALSE`.

Comment: First value is ```TRUE``` because both fourth and fifth values are in the 90-360 day window, both are of the same id and both have *string* repeared as *a*. The fifth value is the last value for id 1, time-wise, therefore there can be no later observations that would have the same strinbg in the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do` ([link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html)) in conjunction with `dplyr`'s `group_by`. `do` is helpful in applying user-defined functions on groups of a dataframe in R.

```
library(dplyr)

#Helper function to add tags
tagger = function(id, date, string){

#get time difference between consecutive dates
  time_diff = diff(date) %>% as.numeric()  
  tags = c()
  if (length(time_diff) !=0){
    for (i in 1:length(time_diff)){
      tag_temp = sapply(cumsum(time_diff[i:length(time_diff)]), FUN = function(x) (x>90) & (x<366))
      tags[i] = sum(tag_temp)
    }
  }
  
  return(data.frame(tag_ = as.numeric(  c(tags,0 )), date =date )) #return data_frame, add 0 for the last entry
}


df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-28","2020-08-15","2020-01-01","2020-05-01","2020-03-01")), string = c('a','b','b','a','a','a','a','b'))

#for each id and string, check for occurrence using tagger function
intermediat_result = df %>% group_by(id,string) %>% arrange(date) %>% do(tagger(.$id,.$date,.$string))

#return the final result
df %>% left_join(intermediat_result) 

#    id  date     string tag_
# 1  1 2020-01-01      a    1
# 2  1 2020-02-01      b    0
# 3  1 2020-03-01      b    0
# 4  1 2020-03-28      a    1
# 5  1 2020-08-15      a    0
# 6  2 2020-01-01      a    1
# 7  2 2020-05-01      a    0
# 8  2 2020-03-01      b    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)

group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(nexthalfyr = runner(x = string, f = function(x) unique(x), k = "270 days", 
                                  lag = "-360 days", idx = date),
         restart = ifelse(nexthalfyr == "character(0)", FALSE, string %in% nexthalfyr))
```

It is probably too complicated, the workaround with ifelse is shameful, but it works.